# Is there a way to define custom implicit GNU Make rules?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, gnu-make

I'm often creating `png` files out of `dot` (graphviz format) files. The command to do so is the following:

```
$ dot my_graph.dot -o my_graph.png -Tpng
```

However, I would like to be able to have a shorter command format like `$ make my_graph.dot` to automatically generate my png file.

For the moment, I'm using a Makefile in which I've defined the following rule, but the recipe is only available in the directory containing the Makefile

```
%.eps: %.dot
    dot $<  -o $@ -Teps
```

**Is it possible to define custom implicit GNU Make recipes ?** Which would allow the above recipe to be available system-wide

**If not, what solution do you use to solve those kind of problem ?**

Setup:

- Fedora Linux with ZSH/Bash

Comment: I believe there is nothing which can be configured as a default makefile if no other makefile is present. You may alias your make with a little script which checks for a makefile in current directory, if NOT present, point to the default one with make -f somedir/Makefile.

Comment: The command `make my_graph.dot` would try to make the named file`my_graph.dot` from something else. With the Makefile you would have to use `make my_graph.eps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define shell functions in your shell's startup files, e.g.

```
dotpng()
{
    echo dot ${1%.dot}.dot -o ${1%.dot}.png -Tpng;
}
```

This function can be called like

```
dotpng my_graph.dot
```

or

```
dotpng my_graph
```

<sub>The code `${1%.dot}.dot` strips `.dot` from the file name if present and appends it (again) to allow both `my_graph.dot` and `my_graph` as function argument.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to define custom implicit GNU Make recipes ?

Not without modifying the source code of GNU Make.

> If not, what solution do you use to solve those kind of problem ?

I wouldn't be a fan o modyfying the system globally, but you could do:

- Create a file `/usr/local/lib/make/myimplicitrules.make` with the content

  ```
    %.eps: %.dot
        dot $<  -o $@ -Teps
  ```
- Use `include /usr/local/lib/make/myimplicitrules.make` in your Makefile.

I would rather use a git submodule or similar to share common configuration between projects, rather than depending on global configuration. Depending on global environment will make your program hard to test and non-portable.

I would rather go with a shell function, something along:

```
mymake() {
   make -f <(cat <<'EOF'
%.eps: %.dot
    dot $<  -o $@ -Teps
EOF
   ) "$@"
}
mymake my_graph.dot
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll use the git submodule idea on future projects if I need to share common Make rules or config files !

Answer (score 1):

GNU Make lets you specify extra makefiles to read using the `MAKEFILES`
environment variable. Quoting from `info '(make)MAKEFILES Variable'`:

> the default goal is never taken from one of these makefiles (or any 
> makefile included by them) and it is not an error if the files listed 
> in 'MAKEFILES' are not found

> if you are running 'make' without a specific makefile, a makefile 
> in 'MAKEFILES' can do useful things to help the built-in implicit 
> rules work better

As an example, with no makefile in the current directory and the
following `.mk` files in `make`'s include path (e.g. via
`MAKEFLAGS=--include-dir="$HOME"/.local/lib/make/`) you can create
subdir `gen/` and convert `my_graph.dot` or `dot/my_graph.dot` by
running:

```sh
MAKEFILES=dot.mk make gen/my_graph.png
```

To further save some typing it's tempting to add `MAKEFILES=dot.mk`
to a session environment but defining `MAKEFILES` in startup files
can make things completely nontransparent. For that reason I prefer
seeing `MAKEFILES=…` on the command line.

File: `dot.mk`

```makefile
include common.mk

genDir ?= gen/
dotDir ?= dot/
dotFlags ?= $(if $(DEBUG),-v)
Tvariant ?= :cairo:cairo

vpath %.dot $(dotDir)

$(genDir)%.png $(genDir)%.svg $(genDir)%.eps : %.dot | $(genDir).
    dot $(dotFlags) $< -o $@ -T'$(patsubst .%,%,$(suffix $@))$(Tvariant)'
```

The included `common.mk` is where you'd store general definitions to
manage directory creation, diagnostics etc., e.g.

```makefile
.PRECIOUS: %/. ## preempt 'unlink: ...: Is a directory'
%/. : ; $(if $(wildcard $@),,mkdir -p -- $(@D))
```

References:

- `?=` `=` `:=` … - `info '(make)Reading Makefiles'`
- `vpath`  - `info '(make)Selective Search'`
- order-only prerequisites (e.g. `| $(genDir).`) - `info '(make)Prerequisite Types'`
- `.PRECIOUS` - `info '(make)Chained Rules'`